# How to dynamically changing the color of a fontawesome thumb defined in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc

In an ASP.NET MVC partial view, I have 2 thumbs defined in a paragraph.

The CSS (fontawesome) will change the color to blue when I hover.

Based upon an if statement truth, I want to change the color of the thumbs. The idea being that if the User had previously clicked the Like or Dislike thumb, I want that selection (the thumb) indicated by the color green the next time in. It shows that they already like or disliked it.

How do I dynamically change the color of the thumbs given the way I display them in a paragraph?

```
@model GbngWebClient.Models.LikeOrDislikeVM

<style>
    .fa {
       cursor: pointer;
       user-select: none;
    }

   .fa:hover {
       color: blue;
   }

  .my-size {
      font-size: 20px;
   }
</style>

<div class="row">
<p><span class="blogLike my-size fa fa-thumbs-up"></span><span class="my-size"> : 
@Model.LikeCount</span> <span class="my-size"> | </span><span class="blogDisLike my-size fa fa- 
thumbs-down"></span><span class="my-size"> : @Model.DisLikeCount</span></p>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
     SetLike('@Model.LikeDisabled');
     SetDisLike('@Model.DisLikeDisabled');

    function SetLike(disabledSwitch) {
        $(".blogLike").attr('disabled', disabledSwitch);

        if (disabledSwitch == false )
        {
            // Show by color that it was previously liked.

            // Does not work.
            $(".blogLike").color('green');
        }
    }

    function SetDisLike(disabledSwitch) {
        $(".blogDisLike").attr('disabled', disabledSwitch);

        if (disabledSwitch == false)
        {
            // Show by color that it was previously liked.

            // Does not work.
            $(".blogDisLike").color('green');
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".blogDisLike").css('color', 'green');
```